# Multiple Expected values dynamoDB

Tags: java, conditional-statements, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update an item conditionally in Dynamo DB. Right now I am able to work with one expected value through this

```
expectedValues.put("Status",
        new ExpectedAttributeValue()
        .withComparisonOperator("EQ")
        .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(StatusCond1)));
```

Now I want to check if Status is equal to one of two expected values. I tried to replace the last line with

```
.withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withSS(StatusCond1, StatusCond2)));
```

but to no avail. I don't understand how to use conditional operators here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the IN operator.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html

"IN : checks for matching elements within two sets"